# Configuring mingw32 and MSYS (Error executing binaries from /mingw/bin)

Tags: mingw, msys

I have installed MSYS, and have configured the path to /mingw/bin directory.
But when i execute the gcc, g++ or any command in /mingw/bin folder is gives me the following error..

```
$ ./x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
  ./x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++: ./x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++: cannot execute binary file
```

I have used `mingw-w64-bin_x86_64-linux_20121031.tar.bz2` file, and extracted it using WinRar utility..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you encounter `cannot execute binary` file it's because the exe can't run on your system. Assuming you are on windows, maybe it's because you are using a wrong package of MSYS (and the linux in the tar file seams odd...). Try to get a executable package of MinGW like [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/) and install all the components you want in it. You can follow the tutorial [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

**Edited** as the right answer.

Comment: I used the same name as it is present in the bin folder, but it doesn't work....
For, g++ is says command not found..

Comment: Usually, when you encounter `cannot execute binary file` it's because the exe can't run on your system. Assuming you are on windows, maybe it's because you are using a wrong package of MSYS (and the linux in the tar file seams odd...). Try to get a executable package of MinGW like [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/) and install all the components you want in it. You can follow the tutorial [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, i had actually downloaded a wrong package, now its workin fine.. :))

Comment: I edited my first post to match the answer that worked for you.